# Plotting Xarray images with Geoviews on a Google Colaboratory Notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory, python-xarray, geoviews

I'm trying to reproduce the code from this [link](https://geoviews.org/gallery/bokeh/xarray_image.html#bokeh-gallery-xarray-image) on Google Colaboratory but my Colab Notebook crashes for reasons I don't understand. Is it possible to get this to work properly?

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that show what you tried and reproduces the problem you observed.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the crash in this notebook.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XwlC2onMlTW0mepTN16Pd1Mj0g_T3dNV

Answer (score 0):

This issue has to do with the fact that Cartopy and Shapely aren't friends...
Shapely is preinstalled in Google Colab, causing a plain install of Cartopy to give problems.
You will have to uninstall Shapely first and reinstall it with no-binary.

Also in order for Geoviews to show plots in Google Colab you will have to call `gv.extension('bokeh')` in every cell where you want to plot something.

Follow this notebook to see the example code of Geoviews working correctly in Google Colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sI51h7l-ySoW2bLrU-K1LMm-TYNVBlif